# Polar docker compose not found v2

Tags: lightning-network

In recent versions of Docker Compose we no longer have the `docker-compose` command instead we use `docker compose` (mind the space instead of dash) but Polar does not understand this.

**To Reproduce**

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1. Remove old versions of docker-compose
2. Install the most recent version of docker compose
3. The command `docker compose version` should work properly but `docker-compose version` should result in an error
4. Install Polar
5. You'll see this error on the startup

```
Docker Compose  Not Found
{"errno":-2,"code":"ENOENT","syscall":"spawn docker-compose","path":"docker-compose","spawnargs":["version","--short"]}
```

Expected behavior:

Polar should also try `docker compose` and be compatible with recent versions of docker compose.

**Screenshots**
[image: Screenshot from 2023-05-18 13-17-14]

Comment: Hello! This stack exchange is probably not the relevant place to post your bug report. If you have a general question relating to Bitcoin or Lightning relevant to this application that you want to post, please do. But for now you should submit your post above to the Polar issues page: https://github.com/jamaljsr/polar/issues

Comment: Question relates to a bug in a specific application, directed OP to their issues page on Github

Answer (score 1):

For now, it seems like Polar does not support the new v2 docker compose. A workaround can be to install the old docker-compose too.

```
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.29.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

docker-compose --version
```